# Cellular Automata in Matlab

Tags: matlab, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

I'm currently self-teaching myself matlab, and I'm interested in cellular automata that was exhibited in old programs like Wolfram's Life1D and Conway's Game of Life from the early 1980s. Is there any available code that would produce Wolfram's Life1D in matlab in some form? I've searched online but have not found anything. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment similar to http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/su08/assignments/hw/02/index.html. You probably will get advice, but not code at SO.

Comment: Searching "game of life" with google produces many results also with code, e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4798-game-of-life

Comment: There's also Matlab code for the game of life on Stackoverflow as an answer to a code-golf question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499538/code-golf-conways-game-of-life/3514906#3514906

Comment: Thank you, all of these links are quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, the MATLAB file exchange is the place to start your search:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/

Five minutes of poking around already gives several promising links, the first of which implements Life1d.

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26929-elementary-cellular-automata
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27233-conway-game-of-life
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4892-conways-game-of-life-in-3d

For enough details to make your own Life1d implementation you can check out:

- http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/su08/assignments/hw/02/index.html
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html

The trickiest part will probably be plotting the results efficiently.  Again, the MATLAB file exchange would be a good place to look for helper classes.

Comment: Thanks nsanders, I didn't know of the site mathworks.com, or any of these places for MATLAB file exchange. I will certainly take a closer look.