# Optimising the game of life

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, conways-game-of-life

I'm writing a game of life program in mathematica however there is a caveat in that I need to be able to apply the reproduction rules to some percentage of the cells, I want to try a new method using MapAt but liveNeighbors doesn't work elementwise, and I can't think of a way of fixing it without doing exactly what I did before (lots of messy indexing), does anyone have any suggestions? (I am assuming this will be more efficient then the old method, which is listed below, if not please let me know, I am just a beginner!).

What I am trying to do:

```
 Map[ArrayPlot,FixedPointList[MapAt[update[#,liveNeighbors[#]]&,#,coords]&,Board, 1]]
```

What I have done already:

```
LifeGame[ n_Integer?Positive, steps_] := Module [{Board, liveNeighbors, update},
  Board = Table [Random [Integer], {n}, {n}];
  liveNeighbors[ mat_] := 
   Apply[Plus,Map[RotateRight[mat,#]&,{{-1,-1},{-1, 0},{-1,1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]];
  update[1, 2] := 1;
  update[_, 3] := 1;
  update[ _, _] := 0;
  SetAttributes[update, Listable];
 Seed = RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[0.7 UnitStep[x] + 0.3 UnitStep[x - 1], {x, 0, 1, 1}], {n, n}];
 FixedPointList[Table[If[Seed[[i, j]] == 1,update[#[[i, j]], liveNeighbors[#][[i, j]]],#[[i, j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]&, Board, steps]]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In[156]:= 
LifeGame2[n_Integer?Positive, steps_] := 
 Module[{Board, liveNeighbors, update},
  Board = RandomInteger[1, {n, n}];
  liveNeighbors[mat_] := 
   ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
    ArrayPad[mat, 1, "Periodic"]];
  SetAttributes[update, Listable];
  Seed = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.3], {n, n}];
  update[0, el_, nei_] := el;
  update[1, 1, 2] := 1;
  update[1, _, 3] := 1;
  update[1, _, _] := 0;
  FixedPointList[MapThread[update, {Seed, #, liveNeighbors[#]}, 2] &, 
   Board, steps]
  ]
```

This implementation does the same as yours, except is quite a lot faster:

```
In[162]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 res1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[11]; LifeGame[20, 100]];]

Out[162]= {6.3476347, Null}

In[163]:= Timing[BlockRandom[Seed[11]; LifeGame2[20, 100]] == res1]

Out[163]= {0.047, True}
```

Comment: Very nice. `Board = Table[Random[Integer], {n}, {n}];` is very pre V6. Preferred coding currently is `Board = RandomInteger[1, {n, n}];`

Comment: What does the `Seed[11]` in the test part of your code do? There is no `Seed` command AFAIK. Did you intend to write `SeedRandom`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't have to roll your own code for a homework problem, have you considered just using the built-in [`CellularAutomaton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellularAutomaton.html) function?

Straight from the documentation, the 2D CA rule:

```
GameOfLife = {224, {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}, {1, 1}};
```

And iterate over a 100x100 grid for 100 steps:

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[GameOfLife, RandomInteger[1, {100, 100}], {{{100}}}]]
```

[image: output of CellularAutomaton]

It would at least give you a baseline for a speed comparison.

Instead of `MapAt`, you could use `Part` with the `Span` syntax to replace a whole subarray at once:

```
a = ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}];
a[[2 ;; 4, 2 ;; 4]] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

[image: a in MatrixForm]

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

[Here you have my golfed version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499538/code-golf-conways-game-of-life/3513212#3513212)